# Extending ASP.NET Membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

What is the best and simplest way to extend the ASP.NET membership (add/delete/edit user functionalities) provided in ASP.NET. I'm looking to add a 1-2 columns in the `aspnet_users` tables. What do I have to do to make this happen. Editing and adding should edit these 2 extra user columns. Displaying the user should display these 2 extra columns. I'm new to ASP.NET Membership and I don't wanna write a ton of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't extend a membership provider itself: at least, not in this way. What you can and *should* do is rely on Membership just for authentication, and use the same userIDs from your provider as the primary key in a separate table/location to store any additional information about each user.

**Under no circumstances should you roll your own authentication system.**

Comment: This is the method I use and it works great. I also use a view to link the membership user table with the table I created for easy access of information

Comment: "Under no circumstances should you roll your own authentication system." Are you saying ASP.NET membership should be used at all times and never write your own username / password authentication?

Comment: @ChrisCannon There are other pre-written auth systems you can use instead of asp.net membership, if membership does not fit your needs for some reason. But yes, never write your own username/password authentication. Just don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Membership isn't easy to extend in the way you describe - the system is very prescriptive about schemas.

However, Microsoft did add in a possible solution: [ASP.NET Profiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx), which have an extendible field you can use for storing profile data. This is useful, however you can't run relational queries against these fields (as they're stored in a blob field in the actual database).

If you actually want to really change the nature of membership and authentication (and profile state) in your application then I'd give ASP.NET Membership a miss and roll everything by yourself.